How to Create Section Headers in Stata Output
I am new to using Stata and I am currently trying to learn how to better organize the output of my Stata scripts for easier reading and presentation. I've seen some outputs that have visually distinct section headers, and I'm interested in learning how to create these in my own work.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
**************************
***** Exploring data *****
**************************


How can I insert such headers into the output of a Stata do-file?
Are there specific commands or scripts that I can use to make these headers appear every time I run a set of commands?

Just want to know how to do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Here is some technique:
di 26 * "*"
di (5 * "*") " Exploring data " (5 * "*")
di 26 * "*"

